# How to close a view in in RCP Application?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, swt, rcp

I have a RCP Application with number of views. There is a 'Welcome' view and other views. Whenever I select 'Welcome' view, other views are closed using the code,

```
PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().hideView(viewID);
```

(Note : Dependency of other plug-in is added to the plug-in where 'Welcome' view is present.)

The same way, I want to close 'Welcome' view when I select any other views from coolbar or Show view dialog. The problem is, if I use the same code as above by adding the dependency, it is causing cyclic dependency in my application and throwing errors. How do I do it without causing cyclic dependency?

Comment: That is the correct code and doesn't, in itself, create a cyclic dependency. What are the exact messages you are getting? Where are you trying to use this?

Comment: @greg-449 : I am using it in createPartControl() method.
I am adding dependency of other views in the plug-in where 'Welcome' view is present. Now If I add dependency of 'Welcome' view plug-in to other plug-ins to hide 'Welcome' view, it is causing cyclic dependency.

Comment: You don't need to add dependencies to the plugin containing the view you are trying to close. All you need is the view id. Cyclic dependency means you have two plugins which depend on each other - this is not allowed as it means the builder can't work out which one to build first.

Comment: @greg-449 : Thank you greg. It worked. I was trying to add viewID using the class name. Now i am directly passing the viewID of the required class.

Comment: Most views don't use the class name as the id anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the correct code to close a view.

You don't need to make the plug-in which contains the view a dependency of the plug-in which is doing the close. All you need is the view id.

Cyclic dependency means you have two plug-ins A and B with A depending on B and B depending on A. This is not allowed because there is no way to build the plug-ins cleanly. You need to change the dependencies to remove the cycle.